# Cannot install vagrant-berkshelf plugin

Tags: vagrant, berkshelf

I've updated to Vagrant 1.4.3 and am attempting to install the vagrant-berkshelf plugin. I'm getting the following error:

```
$ vagrant plugin install vagrant-berkshelf
Installing the 'vagrant-berkshelf' plugin. This can take a few minutes...
/opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/installer.rb:184:in `check_executable_overwrite': "minitar" from minitar conflicts with installed executable from archive-tar-minitar (Gem::InstallError)
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/installer.rb:384:in `block in generate_bin'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/installer.rb:371:in `each'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/installer.rb:371:in `generate_bin'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/installer.rb:231:in `install'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:379:in `block in install'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:339:in `each'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:339:in `each_with_index'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:339:in `install'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.3/plugins/commands/plugin/action/install_gem.rb:65:in `block in call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.3/plugins/commands/plugin/gem_helper.rb:42:in `block in with_environment'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/user_interaction.rb:40:in `use_ui'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.3/plugins/commands/plugin/gem_helper.rb:41:in `with_environment'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.3/plugins/commands/plugin/action/install_gem.rb:52:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.3/plugins/commands/plugin/action/bundler_check.rb:20:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.3/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:69:in `block in run'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.3/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:69:in `run'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.3/plugins/commands/plugin/command/base.rb:17:in `action'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.3/plugins/commands/plugin/command/install.rb:27:in `execute'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.3/plugins/commands/plugin/command/root.rb:56:in `execute'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.3/lib/vagrant/cli.rb:38:in `execute'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.3/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:484:in `cli'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.3/bin/vagrant:127:in `<top (required)>'
from /opt/vagrant/bin/../embedded/gems/bin/vagrant:23:in `load'
from /opt/vagrant/bin/../embedded/gems/bin/vagrant:23:in `<main>'
```

I tried to manually install minitar with both the system and Vagrant-specific rubies. System ruby installed it just fine. When I manually installed it into the Vagrant ruby, I got the following:

```
$ sudo /opt/vagrant/embedded/bin/gem install minitar
Fetching: minitar-0.5.4.gem (100%)
minitar's executable "minitar" conflicts with archive-tar-minitar
Overwrite the executable? [yN]  y
Successfully installed minitar-0.5.4
Parsing documentation for minitar-0.5.4
Installing ri documentation for minitar-0.5.4
1 gem installed
```

But, I still get the exact same error. I've tried to manually install every gem in the Gemfile from the vagrant-berkshelf github repo and still cannot install.

Answer (score 4):

I asked in https://github.com/berkshelf/vagrant-berkshelf/issues/140 and received the following answer.

It was a conflict with a dependency in vagrant-chef-librarian. The solution was to manually install minitar with the following command:

```
$ /opt/vagrant/embedded/bin/gem install minitar --install-dir ~/.vagrant.d/gems
minitar's executable "minitar" conflicts with archive-tar-minitar
Overwrite the executable? [yN]  y
Successfully installed minitar-0.5.4
Parsing documentation for minitar-0.5.4
Installing ri documentation for minitar-0.5.4
1 gem installed
```

The bit I'd missed was the install-dir.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently [Vagrant Berkshelf has been retired](https://sethvargo.com/the-future-of-vagrant-berkshelf/) as of 5 days ago.

To use Chef with Vagrant, [here is a good article](http://misheska.com/blog/2013/06/16/getting-started-writing-chef-cookbooks-the-berkshelf-way/).

Note the "Note" on that page:

> NOTE: As of Tuesday, January 28th the Vagrantfile and the vagrant-bershelf
>   plugin are being retired You can do everything mentioned in this article (vagrant up, vagrant provision, etc.) with Test Kitchen and its .kitchen.yml covered in Part 3 of this series. Consider skipping ahead to Part 3 and just start using Test Kitchen now. This article will be retained just for historical purposes.

So follow [this link](http://misheska.com/blog/2013/08/06/getting-started-writing-chef-cookbooks-the-berkshelf-way-part3/) and use Test Kitchen instead of Vagrant Berkshelf. I have not tried this yet but I am in the same boat as you -- looking to get Chef Solo working with Vagrant.

Answer (score 1):

Up to now, the Test Kitchen setup cannot do everything e.g. multi machine setups. You can replace vagrant-berkshelf with a local Berkshelf installation and using vagrant-triggers to do cookbook vendoring on "vagrant up" or "vagrant provision".

I have written a [short blog post](http://blog.neovatar.org/index.php/archives/41-Replace-vagrant-berkshelf-with-berkshelf-and-vagrant-triggers.html) about it.

Basically it boils down to:

- Install Ruby/Berkshelf
- Install vagrant-triggers Vagrant plug-in
- Use vagrant-trigger to vendor cookbooks in a directory
- Run the Vagrant chef-solo provisioner

The following Vagrantfile snippet will use the vagrant-triggers plug-in to call a locally installed Berkshelf:

```
  [:up, :provision].each do |cmd|
    config.trigger.before cmd, :stdout => true do
      info 'Cleaning cookbook directory'
      run "rm -rf #{cookbooks_path}"
      info 'Installing cookbook dependencies with berkshelf'
      run "berks vendor #{cookbooks_path}"
    end
  end
```

This will execute Berkshelf to install the needed cookbooks in the "cookbook" directory, which is mounted in your vagrant VM and used by the Vagrant chef-solo provisioner by default.