# Vagrant cannot install nokogiri-dependent plugins

Tags: plugins, vagrant, osx-mavericks

I'm trying to install the rackspace plugin for vagrant (1.5.1):

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant-rackspace
```

But it complains

> Bundler, the underlying system Vagrant uses to install plugins,
>   reported an error. The error is shown below. These errors are usually
>   caused by misconfigured plugin installations or transient network
>   issues. The error from Bundler is:
>
> An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.6.1), and Bundler
>   cannot continue. Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.1'`
>   succeeds before bundling.

However `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.1'` and `/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/bin/gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.1'` both work.

I've looked at a bunch of SO threads and blog posts. Things I've tried that have not worked

1. Running `xcode-select --install`
2. Installing full xcode
3. brew install gcc-4.2
4. Remove rvm and rvm version of ruby
5. Install nokogiri w/ built-in (mac) ruby and vagrant-embedded ruby

Despite the fact that nokogiri installs fine (#5 above) without sudo on both counts, `vagrant plugin install vagrant-rackspace` still fails...

So, in summary, I **can** install the nokogiri plugin, however I **cannot** install the vagrant rackspace plugin, can you help me get the plugin installed?

Related threads

- [Error to install Nokogiri on OSX 10.9 Maverick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19643153/error-to-install-nokogiri-on-osx-10-9-maverick/19643909#19643909)
- [nokogiri - ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6753000/nokogiri-error-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension)

**Full output of** [vagrant plugin install vagrant-rackspace --debug](http://pastebin.com/Y5umhsci)

Comment: Try finding the install and build logs from `~/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/nokogiri-1.6.1/`. Even if you use the embedded gem, GEM_HOME etc. still point to your default places, not to the Vagrant's internal gem storages.

Comment: The only log I can find is `/Users/nathannobbe/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/nokogiri-1.6.1/ext/nokogiri/gem_make.out`. Basically useless, but this is what it says - `/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/bin/ruby: invalid option -H  (-h will show valid options) (RuntimeError)`

Comment: For the hell of it this morning I tried `vagrant plugin install vagrant-aws`, same problem as the rackspace plugin.

Comment: Both use fog which depends on nokogiri, so that's expected. :/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm on OSX Mavericks and this worked for me:

Set as environment property:

```
NOKOGIRI_USE_SYSTEM_LIBRARIES=1
```

Then install as usual:

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant-rackspace
```

Comment: This is much less hacky than the accepted solution.

Comment: Lol, the only reason my answer was accepted is because nobody answered it before I figured out *something* that worked...

Comment: I also had to set the compiler to the default compiler: `sudo port select gcc none`. Compilation failed with the gcc set to gcc 4.8.

Comment: Just FYI, this can be done inline with the call `NOKOGIRI_USE_SYSTEM_LIBRARIES=1 vagrant plugin install vagrant-rackspace`

Answer (score 3):

Vagrant ships with embedded Ruby and isolated gem environment. So installing gems manually to your "normal" gem environment won't help.

The first issue is that you should never use sudo to run any vagrant command. If possible, please remove ~/.vagrant.d/ or at least chown it recursively back to your own user. You could also try upgrading Vagrant to v1.5.1.

Then please gist/pastebin the output of `vagrant plugin install vagrant-rackspace --debug` and ~/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/nokogiri-1.6.1/ext/nokogiri/mkmf.log.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on sudo. I've learned a lot about gems and what-not over the past few days.

Answer (score 2):

The posted solutions didn't work for me.  Instead I needed to specify the libxml2, libxslt and libiconv that I [installed with homebrew](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html) **(Do this first)**.

I installed the [gem manually with the embedded ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21096659/cannot-install-vagrant-berkshelf-plugin) with the following [very concise] command line:

```
    /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/bin/gem install \ # select the embedded ruby
      --install-dir ~/.vagrant.d/gems \              # install to the vagrant dir
      nokogiri -v '1.6.2.1' -- \                     # pass options to nokogiri install
      --with-xml2-include=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.7.8/include/libxml2 \
      --with-xml2-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.7.8/lib \
      --with-xslt-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/libxslt/1.1.26 \
      --with-iconv-include=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.13.1/include \
      --with-iconv-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.13.1/lib
```

Comment: It's a painful problem to deal with. They should just use the system Ruby instead of their own bundled derivative.

Comment: that has its own set of issues, @quickshiftin. you can very quickly get into the Ruby Gem equivalent of DLL Hell with incompatible versions of gems/libraries/development tools if you rely on or require them to be installed systemwide.

Comment: @MarkReed In the PHP world we can at least manage to share the same interpreter lol. Do they not have a proper dependency management system for gems?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me on Mavericks and Vagrant 1.6.1:

```
CC=/usr/bin/gcc vagrant plugin install vagrant-rackspace
```

I tried `NOKOGIRI_USE_SYSTEM_LIBRARIES=1` but got an error saying that system libxml2 is too old.

Answer (score 0):

Warning: This is a **super-hacky** *solution*, though it's hard to call it that.

Yesterday I installed Vagrant on another OSX Mavericks box. Like many other posts I read on SO *"all I had to do"* was run `xcode-select --install` and bingo `vagrant plugin install vagrant-rackspace` worked like a charm.

Today I was mired down in the Bundler code again when it dawned on me that since this is an isolated ruby environment why not nuke my `~/.vagrant.d` directory and copy the same directory from the successful build on the other box...

The result? A working `vagrant rackspace` on my laptop! I'm not sure I'll ever figure out what was really wrong, but if anyone wants a shot at the 100 point bounty, I'm still open to suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

In my case the nokogiri folders and their files located in `~/vagrant.d/gems/gems` had wrong rights (user/group).

After changing them to `username:staff` (`username` being your console user name), it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Similarly with my case, I have an issue while installing `vagrant-omnibus` plugin for Vagrant 1.6.3 on OSX Mavericks 10.9.4 and ruby 2.0.0p247 rbenv.

I tried setting the env NOKOGIRI_USE_SYSTEM_LIBRARIES to 1 or true, then update+install but the same error still  there.

I found that there is a suggestion in https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/3769 to use the specify the baked in nokogiri version and this works for me. So, I also wrote a quick [noted](http://zdk.github.io/vagrant-1.6.3-nokogiri-depended-plugin-installation-quickfix/) for myself to refer this unfortunates issue.

Answer (score 0):

If Nate Murray's solution doesn't work, I found upgrading to a Vagrant version > 1.6.4 fixed the issue (as noted in this Github issue: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/3769)

Answer (score 0):

in my case while trying to install vagrant-parallels, i had to check the Command line tools folder had an error in the naming for some reason. Fixing that allowed nokigiri to work well